# why start the taylor series of $\cos^{2} x$ at $k=1$ and not just $k=0$ as I do not understand the problem with $2^{-1}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

Im using $\cos^2 x=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x))$ and $\cos x = (-1)^k \frac{(2x)^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ to find the sum for the Taylor series of $\cos^2 x$. I thought I was getting it. When I find the answer $$\cos^{2} x =\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{2^{(2k-1)}x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$ however, my textbook does one more step and starts at $k=1$ instead of $k=0$. Which they make $$\cos^{2} x = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{2^{2k-1}x^{2k}}{{2k}!}$$I understand that they do this to prevent $2^{-1}$ at $k=0$, but i dont understand what would be the problem of $2^{-1}$ as negative powers work fine. I dont understand why this last step is made. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you put dollar signs around the math and braces { } around the exponents that will do the majority of the latex for you

Comment: no problem. If you're interested in learning Latex (I'd strongly recommend it) the not so short guide to latex is pretty good (just google the title) and then generally just google symbols, etc. that you're unsure of

Comment: It seems I didnt even need the brackets, dollar signs was all it took. Thanks!

Comment: I've done some tinkering. Does all of that look right to you?

Comment: the braces are necessary when the exponents are more than one character so you get $x^{2k}$ instead of $x^2k$

Comment: oh i see

also i think we were tinkering at the same time :)

Comment: I had done editing but you undo it

Comment: Oops, sorry I did not notice.

Comment: don't worry, this happens a bit. You'll find that if you don't typeset questions nicely, someone is sure to swoop in within a minute or two to edit it all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now some mathematical corrections and answers.

$$\cos (x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k (x)^{2k}/(2k)!,$$

$$\cos (2x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k (2x)^{2k}/(2k)!.$$

Hence

\begin{align}\cos^2 (x) &=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos (2x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k (2x)^{2k}/(2k)!=\\&=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k 2^{2k-1}x^{2k}/(2k)!=\\&=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k 2^{2k-1}x^{2k}/(2k)!.
\end{align}

In the last step, in order to start the summation at $k=1$ I just evaluated the expression for $k=0$ (and got $1/2$).

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and the explanation. Is there a reason to start at k=1?

Comment: Not really. I suppose the one out the front is more aesthetically pleasing that the half and it's also nice to combine the constant terms so that the sum only involves terms including x.